convolution of an order statistics and an exponential distribution
Is there a simplification to the convolution of the k-th order statistics from an erlang distribution with shape 2:
$f_{1_{(k)}}(z) = \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!} \cdot \left(1-e^{-\lambda z} (\lambda  z+1)\right)^{k-1} \cdot \left(e^{-\lambda z} (\lambda  z+1) \right)^{n-k} \cdot \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda z}z$
and a pdf $f_2$ of an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$, knowing that the convolution of two functions is given by the following formula:
$f_1(x) * f_2(x)=$ $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_1(x) \cdot f_2(t-x)dx$

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Unfortunately, I have been in your shoes. I'm now picky about asking questions this way.    But you'll get it I'm certain.
